# Kafka Connect JdbcSinkConnector - error on INSERT (invalid byte sequence)

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We have data replication solution using Kafka Connect. Data is being read using Debezium SqlServerConnector into multiple topics, and then written to PostgreSQL using JdbcSinkConnector. Each topic/table has dedicated sink.

Now we are having error on one of the sinks: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00`

One of replicated records has some non-printable characters in text column. Message is placed in Kafka topic successfully, but then it fails when sink connector is writing into target table.

Target tables are created automatically, we are using `“auto.create”: “true”`

Source field (SQL Server): NVARCHAR(400)

Target field (PostgreSQL): TEXT

Now we need to fix it. I see two options:

1. (preferred) find a way to write data as is, including non-printable characters
2. remove non-printable characters, either in source connector, or in sink.

I was looking for some Kafka Connect transformation that we could use, but no luck so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which character set and collation  have both fields?

Comment: Source collation: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` . Target collation: `en_US.UTF-8` (database default)

Comment: use always the same character set collations for that or you need to convert it prior to sending

Comment: Well these are different RDBMS - MS SQL Server vs. PostgreSQL. I'm not sure there is an exact equivalent for SQL Server collation in Postgres. I could try to convert string, but I could not find any suitable options in JdbcSinkConnector config.

Comment: there are none, as afar as i can tell also, so the best solution is to have the same on bith databases